# creating https.request equivalent using axios

Tags: node.js, express, https, axios

I have been playing around with APIs using node and https, but I wanted to find out more about using Axios. I creating a route to post data into a list using the Mailchimp API using https, body-parser, and express. I wanted to know can I modify the below code to use Axios instead? in particular the https.request functionality where there is a request.write() and request.end() functions.

I was searching online but could not find something similar for Axios. Finally is it even worth using Axios instead of https?

```
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const firstname = req.body.first_name;
  const lastname = req.body.last_name;
  const email = req.body.email;
  console.log(`details ${firstname}, ${lastname}, ${email}`);

  const data = {
    members: [
      {
        email_address: email,
        status: "subscribed",
        merge_fields: {
          FNAME: firstname,
          LNAME: lastname,
        },
      },
    ],
  };

  let jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
  const url = "https://usxx.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/123456789";
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    auth: "test:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-usxx"
  };

  const request = https.request(url, options, (response) => {
    let statusCode = response.statusCode;
    error = statusCode >= 400 && statusCode <= 500;
    if (error) {
      res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/failure.html`);
    } else if (statusCode >= 200 && statusCode <= 300) {
      res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/success.html`);
    }
    response.on("data", (data) => {
      console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    });
  });

  request.write(jsonData);
  request.end();
});
```